# Google sheets - is it possible to enter a formula in a cell, using the data from the same cell?

Tags: google-sheets

In google sheets, is it possible to enter a formula in a cell, using the data from the same cell?

Comment: It should be possible with google apps script (their VBA equivalent) - get value of A1, calculate something, then replace A1's value with the result. But I'm not familiar with that, and it's probably not what you are looking for.

Comment: I asked on quora as well, one guy gave me a solution. Basically you have to have three spreadsheets to work on, but eventually it does work out

Comment: It's probably easier to just add a cell. You can set its font color to its background color, if looks are a concern.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly. But you can have a duplicate sheet, with the duplicated sheets referencing the other one with the proper formula for any change you want.

For example you want an updated 'view' sheet (B)for some other user that also  change some value based  on the data you have on your sheet (A) but you dont want them messing with your Sheet (A).

The solution is to create a sheet B that references sheet A , for example by using `IMPORTRANGE` if you want to just show information, or the a formula that involves referencing data from your sheet A.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is really simple : no. Because of a really simple algorithm :

```
1 - Target cell formula's parameter and go to step 2
2 - If a targeted cell changed go to step 3 else finish the treatment
3 - Evaluate the formula, display the value into the cell and finish the treatment
```

Comment: Makes sense, I guess its easiest to add a cell